# Powers of $2$ or $3$ from $m$ to $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a formula for finding how many powers of $2$ or $3$ exist in a given range of numbers say $m$ through $n$ or $0$ through $n$?

Comment: That's the same as the number of integers in $[\log_2 m, \log_2 n]$ (and similarly for $3$).

Comment: In short: $\lfloor\log_b n\rfloor-\lceil\log_b m\rceil+1$.

Comment: @Sri: So that's $\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor - \lceil \log_2(m) \rceil + 1$ if I'm not mistaken. And Kedar: If $m = 0$ then you will find infinitely many solutions, as $0 < 2^{-n} < 1$ for all $n = 1, 2, \ldots$.

Comment: @Kedar Your question now seems slightly ambiguous. See my answer and Eric's answers for 2 different interpretations. Can you clarify what you had in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*ADDED: I am taking the phrase "powers of $2$" to mean nonnegative integral powers $\{1,2,4, \ldots\}$.*

Assume that $n \geq m \geq 1$. (If $m =0$, then you can safely redefine it to be $1$.) Notice that $2^k \in [m,n] \iff k \in [\log_2 m, \log_2 n]$. Further, if $k$ is an integer, then<sup>1</sup>:
$$
2^k \in [m,n] \iff k \in [\ \lceil \log_2 m \rceil, \lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor \ ].
$$
Be careful with the floors and ceilings. Therefore the number of powers of two in the given range is:
$$
\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor - \lceil \log_2 m \rceil + 1.
$$

Proceed similarly for $3$.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is because of the following facts. If $k$ is an integer and $x$ real, then $k \leq x$ is equivalent to saying $k \leq \lfloor x \rfloor$. Similarly, $k \geq x \iff k \geq \lceil x \rceil$.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for numbers composed only from the primes $2$ and $3$ (For $n\leq 10$ this would be $2,3,4,6,8,9$) then see [this Math Stack Exchange thread.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15966/ramanujans-first-letter-to-hardy-and-the-number-of-3-smooth-integers)  It turns out there are approximately $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\log N}{\log 2} + 1\right)\left(\dfrac{\log N}{\log 3} + 1\right).$$

(Counting lattice points in the triangle)

Comment: Hmm, that's a good catch! :)